# How do I disable Alfresco main menu items?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

The main menu on the Alfresco Share app contains a couple of items that the project team for our deployment wants to have disabled.  Specifically "My Files" and "Shared Files".  Hiding would be good enough, but if we can disable them completely that would be best.  Those are functions that the users are not to have any access to.  All their interactions should be through the sites.

Is there an Alfresco supported (as in "won't break when we upgrade versions") way to do this?

Comment: which version are you talking about?

Comment: We're currently on 4.2e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have blog post describing how to hide main menu items at [this](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/09/16/customizing-the-share-header-part-3/) link. It turned out later that this approach wasn't working on versions below 4.2.2. which is the case with your community version (4.2e) too.

You can use workaround described at [this](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-19930) link. 
Below is the exact code you need. 
At the bottom of **share-header.get.js** add following

```
var widget, widgetsToRemove = [ "HEADER_SHARED_FILES", "HEADER_MY_FILES" ], idx, max;

for (idx = 0, max = widgetsToRemove.length; idx < max; idx++)
{  
    findAndRemoveIn(model.jsonModel.widgets, null, null, widgetsToRemove[idx]);
}


function findAndRemoveIn(obj, arrContext, arrIdx, id) {
var idx, max, key;
if (obj !== undefined && obj !== null) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj) === "[object Object]") {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("id") && obj.id === id) {
            if (arrContext !== null && arrIdx !== null)
            { arrContext.splice(arrIdx, 1); }

            else
            { logger .debug("Unexpected match outside of array structure: " + jsonUtils.toJSONString(obj)); }

        } else {
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                { findAndRemoveIn(obj[key], null, null, id); }

            }
        }
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj) === "[object Array]") {
        for (idx = 0, max = obj.length; idx < max; idx++)
        { findAndRemoveIn(obj[idx], obj, idx, id); }

    }
  }
}
```

Later you can write extension module when you get this working. 
Other elements such as HEADER_NAVIGATION_MENU_BAR, HEADER_TITLE_MENU, HEADER_TITLE can be removed from menu using **widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray** helper function. 
Last option is to use CSS.

Comment: I used this on 4.2f, and it worked out. You know your goals. :)

Comment: AFAIK 4.2.2 is enterprise version

Comment: I bet it'll work on 4.2e version. However I don't think you should have problems with using 4.2f

Comment: Hmmm, I must be doing something wrong.  Crashes Alfresco with a "05200001 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/share/header/share-header.get.js': 05200000 TypeError: Cannot read property "widgets" from null (file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/share/header/share-header.get.js#1917)" error when I insert the javascript into the share-header.get.js file.

Comment: It works now.  I ran into issues with servicerun apparently failing silently, which meant I wasn't always seeing updates.  Rebooting the machine seems the only foolproof way to get Alfresco to completely restart.  Also, one of my earlier issues appears to have been putting the code at the top of the file instead of the bottom...  Thanks!